# Node/Express - bodyParser empty for PUT requests

Tags: node.js, rest, express, put

I'm getting an error with Express in bodyParser is failing to parse any PUT requests... my config is set up like so:

```
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
 app.use(express.methodOverride());
 app.use(express.query());
 app.use(app.router);
```

However everytime I make a PUT request to an endpoint, req.body returns as 'undefined'.

I've tried making request through Chromes REST console, and also via jQuery ajax requests like so:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'https://localhost:4430/api/locations/5095595b3d3b7b10e9f16cc1',
     type: 'PUT',
     data: {name: "Test name"},
     dataType: 'json'
 });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it - was a silly thing by me of setting my routes before the express middleware.

Comment: could you expand a bit on this, i'm having a similar issue with PUT requests.

Answer (score 6):

You also need to set the Content-Type to `application/json`. Your jQuery request should be:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'https://localhost:4430/api/locations/5095595b3d3b7b10e9f16cc1',
     type: 'PUT',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data: JSON.stringify({name: "Test name"}),
     dataType: 'json'
 });
```

Otherwise, the body parser won't attempt to parse the body.

**EDIT**: here is my test code

1. Run `express test`
2. Add a `/test` route in `app.js`:

```
app.all('/test', routes.test);
```

and `routes/index.js`:

```
exports.test = function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send({status: 'ok'});
};
```

1. Link jQuery and the following script in index.jade:

```
$(function () {
  $('#test').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/test',
      type: 'PUT',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify({name: "Test name"}),
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  });
});
```

When I run this, I get the following log:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
GET / 200 26ms - 333
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 2ms
GET /javascripts/test.js 304 1ms
{ name: 'Test name' }
PUT /test 200 2ms - 20
```

Comment: I just tested and it works for me. I will update my answer with my test code.

Comment: Thanks Laurent - I found the problem with my code. I was setting the routes before the express middleware so nothing was going through the bodyParser.